# Why is my ReadTheDocs project not importing?

Tags: svn, read-the-docs

I have had a project that imports and builds on ReadTheDocs for nearly a year. After quite a while without updates, I decided it was time to rebuild the docs. However, the build now fails with a not-very-informative error of:

> Error: Failed to import project: Failed to get code from 
>   'https://subversion.xray.aps.anl.gov/pyGSAS/trunk/' (svn checkout): 1

I located the "wipe" option and tried to see if that would help, but no luck on that either.

I am willing to believe that something related to our repository is the problem (though I have not heard from anyone unable to get access), but I need something more specific and definite before I start rattling the bars of that cage.

Suggestions are most welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Problem turned out to be a SSL certificate problem; ReadTheDocs did not accept our server's certificate.